# Get Discipline of View [Autodesk Model Derivative API]

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I'm trying to get the Discipline Property of a Revit Model uploaded to BIM 360. I was able to get the list of views by GET
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/URL_SAFE_URN_OF_SOURCE_FILE/metadata
However there is no data on Discipline. Where and how can I get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with "Discipline Properties" in Revit but I can comment on the Forge side of things:

The [GET :urn/metadata](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-GET/) endpoint simply returns a list of "viewables" that were extracted from the source design file. In case of Revit, these are typically 3D views or 2D sheets. I'm not aware of any other types of viewables that could be extracted by the Model Derivative service.

If the "discipline property" is a property available on some of the Revit elements, you might want to take a look at the [GET :urn/metadata/:guid/properties](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/) endpoint. This one returns a JSON with properties of objects in one of the extracted viewables. Note that those properties are also accessible from Forge Viewer using its APIs.

In general, the Model Derivative service is trying to extract the "right" amount of information, making sure that the viewer gets all the important data for visualization and analysis, but also making sure that the size of the converted output stays in bounds. If there is some specific information in Revit designs that you need that is not extracted automatically, you can consider using the [Design Automation](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/reference/http/) service to process your Revit models in the cloud and extract all the information with your custom Revit plugin.